# keep getting error 'value of type ' ' has no member ' '

Tags: swift, types, member

I've been stuck in this project for 2 days and I think I really need help.

The program is only half-completed as I can't even get the layout to work. I have a var settings = setting() to link to the class setting(). Within class setting, I have varies vars and func.

originally, I had the class put in a different swift file in the project, but because Swift keeps giving me the 'type has no member' error, I decided to put the class in the ContentView.swift. but even then, Swift seems to selectively dis-recognise my vars in the class instance and I can't exactly pinpoint why.

e.g. the first line with error 'value of type 'setting' ha no member '$playerChoice'' says it cant find settings.playerChoice, whilst not listing the same error on the line underneath to look for settings.playerChoice in the String interpolation. I tried turning the program off and on, shift cmd K to re-compile preview a few times, it didn't work.

Can someone please have a look for me what exactly went wrong? Thank you.

my codes are as follow:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class setting {
    var playerChoice : Int = 0
    var questionCount : Int = 0

    var pcRandom : Int = 0
    var correctAnswer = 0
    var question : String = ""
    var buttonArray = [Int]()

    var enteredAnswer = ""
    var gameRound : Int = 0
    var scoreCount : Int = 0
    var title2 = ""

    var alertTitle = ""
    var alertMessage = ""
    var alertEndGame = false

    func refreshGame() {
        pcRandom = Int.random(in: 1 ... 12)
        correctAnswer = playerChoice * pcRandom
        question = "\(playerChoice) times \(pcRandom) is??"
    }

    func compareAnswer() {
        let answerModified = enteredAnswer
        let answerModified2 = answerModified.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        if Int(answerModified2) == correctAnswer {
            scoreCount += 1
            title2 = "RIGHT"
        }
        else {
            title2 = "WRONG"
        }

        if gameRound > questionCount {
            alertTitle = "Game Ended"
            alertMessage = "You got \(scoreCount) over \(questionCount)"
            alertEndGame = true
            }
        else {
            refreshGame()
        }
        gameRound += 1
        gameRound += 1
    }
}
```

```
var settings = setting()

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Section (header: Text("Getting Your Settings Righttt").font(.title)) {
                    Form {
                        Stepper(value: settings.$playerChoice, in: 1...13, step: 1) { //value of type 'setting' ha no member '$playerChoice'
                            if settings.playerChoice == 13 {Text("All")}
                            else {
                                Text("Multiplication table \(settings.playerChoice)")
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Form {
                        Text("Number of Questions?")
                        Picker(selection: settings.$questionCount, label: Text("Number of Questions?")) { //value of type 'setting' has no member '$questionCount'
                        ForEach (settings.questionCountArray, id: \.self) {Text("\($0)")} } ////value of type 'setting' ha no member '$questionCountArray'
                            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    }
                    Spacer()

                    Button("Tap to start") {
                        settings.refreshGame
                    }
            }

            Section (header: Text("Game Play").font(.title)){
                Text(settings.question)
                    TextField("Enter your answer", text: settings.$enteredAnswer, onCommit: settings.compareAnswer)   //value of type 'setting' ha no member '$enteredAnswer'
                    Text("Your score is currently \(settings.scoreCount)")
                    Text("This is game round \(settings.gameRound) out of \(settings.questionCount)")
                }
            Spacer()
            }
                .alert(isPresented: settings.$alertEndGame) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Game Ended"), message: Text("You reached score \(settings.scoreCount) out of \(settings.questionCount)"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Play Again"))) //game doesnt restart and refresh
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should not prepend $ to the variable name. Or, if you want to use bindings, then you should declare `@State var playerChoice`

Comment: I needed 2 way binding. If I remove the $, it’ll come up with another error. I’ll update this to let you know what the exact error is

Comment: Then you forgot an `@State` annotation to those properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did not check logic, but below fixed code at least compilable, so hope it will be helpful

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Setting: ObservableObject {
    @Published var playerChoice : Int = 0
    var questionCount : Int = 0
    @Published var questionCountArray = [String]()

    var pcRandom : Int = 0
    var correctAnswer = 0
    var question : String = ""
    var buttonArray = [Int]()

    @Published var enteredAnswer = ""
    var gameRound : Int = 0
    var scoreCount : Int = 0
    var title2 = ""

    var alertTitle = ""
    var alertMessage = ""
    @Published var alertEndGame = false

    func refreshGame() {
        pcRandom = Int.random(in: 1 ... 12)
        correctAnswer = playerChoice * pcRandom
        question = "\(playerChoice) times \(pcRandom) is??"
    }

    func compareAnswer() {
        let answerModified = enteredAnswer
        let answerModified2 = answerModified.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        if Int(answerModified2) == correctAnswer {
            scoreCount += 1
            title2 = "RIGHT"
        }
        else {
            title2 = "WRONG"
        }

        if gameRound > questionCount {
            alertTitle = "Game Ended"
            alertMessage = "You got \(scoreCount) over \(questionCount)"
            alertEndGame = true
            }
        else {
            refreshGame()
        }
        gameRound += 1
        gameRound += 1
    }
}

struct ASFContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var settings = Setting()
    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Section (header: Text("Getting Your Settings Righttt").font(.title)) {
                Form {
                    Stepper(value: $settings.playerChoice, in: 1...13, step: 1) { //value of type 'setting' ha no member '$playerChoice'
                        if settings.playerChoice == 13 {Text("All")}
                        else {
                            Text("Multiplication table \(settings.playerChoice)")
                        }
                    }
                }

                Form {
                    Text("Number of Questions?")
                    Picker(selection: $settings.questionCount, label: Text("Number of Questions?")) { //value of type 'setting' has no member '$questionCount'
                        ForEach (settings.questionCountArray, id: \.self) {Text("\($0)")} } ////value of type 'setting' ha no member '$questionCountArray'
                        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
                Spacer()

                Button("Tap to start") {
                    self.settings.refreshGame()
                }
            }

            Section (header: Text("Game Play").font(.title)){
                Text(settings.question)
                TextField("Enter your answer", text: $settings.enteredAnswer, onCommit: settings.compareAnswer)   //value of type 'setting' ha no member '$enteredAnswer'
                Text("Your score is currently \(settings.scoreCount)")
                Text("This is game round \(settings.gameRound) out of \(settings.questionCount)")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $settings.alertEndGame) {
            Alert(title: Text("Game Ended"), message: Text("You reached score \(settings.scoreCount) out of \(settings.questionCount)"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Play Again"))) //game doesnt restart and refresh
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you a lot. I managed to get it to work finally using @Published. The course I am on hasn't taught me that part while expecting me to use it.